# PL/SQL Developer Command Window Script Encoding

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, plsqldeveloper

I am running a sql script through pl/sql Developer Command Windows.It is a simple script with two insert commands that inserts two labels in two different languages (French and English).
Some characters in the French label are inserted with "bad format". Running the query `select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS` returns the values
NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY = AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET = UTF8

My script file is saved in UTF encoding.
I am running in a Windows 10 machine.
Should i change the NLS_LANG value ? if yes what value should i insert ? The labels could be in English and French.
Is there anyway to run the command window in some encoding ? Or none of the those are solutions and i must do something else ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The safest option might be to use `UNISTR` to escape any non-ASCII characters:

```
SQL> select unistr('Fran\00E7ais') label from dual;

LABEL
-----------------
Français
```

I'm sure there is a way to configure your script, operating system, and PL/SQL Developer to natively work with different character sets. But what happens if someone runs the script in SQL*Plus instead? If there are only a few non-ASCII characters, escaping them is probably the easiest solution.